# Doubt in proving $\ln(2)$ is irrational

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, irrational-numbers, ratio

I tried to prove $\ln(2)$ is irrational using the method of contradiction knowing that $e$ is irrational:

> Let $$\ln2=\frac{p}{q}$$ be in simplest form where $p$ and $q$ are positive integers.
>
> Now we have $$e^{\frac{p}{q}}=2$$ $$2^q=e^p$$ Now $2^q$ is always an even positive integer.

How can we reason that $e^p$ can never be an integer?

Comment: There's a proof that $e$ is transcendental, in particular, $e^p$ is irrational for nonzero integers $p$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, if one accepts the fact that $e$ is *transcendental* over $\Bbb Q$, then
$e^p$ cannot be rational, since if

$e^p = r \in \Bbb Q, \tag 1$

then $e$ would be a root of

$x^p - r \in \Bbb Q[x]; \tag 2$

i.e., $e$ would be an *algebraic*, not a transcendental, number.